# Getting Referer from Custom 404 page

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, asp-classic

The custom 404 error only gives you the page that was not found when using `Request.Servervariables("QUERY_STRING")` , Well aware of this.

But how do you get the referer of that page?

`Request.Servervariables("HTTP_REFERER")` in the custom 404 error page, does NOT return the referring page of the page which calls the 404 page.

The pages are in this order:

1. Referring Page to Invalid URL (/home/)
2. Invalid URL (/invalidurl)
3. 404 Error Page (/404)

I'm trying to get the Referring page (1) from the 404 Error Page (3), not the Invalid URL (2) as you do by using the `Request.Servervariables("QUERY_STRING")`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer to this is: no.

Comment: hahahahaha... great answer.. I actually had to do a total work-around using Ajax and cookies.. ohh man so strenuous.

Comment: @ControlFreak could you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't *easily* do this on the server side, but you can on the client side, since the browser keeps history. You just have to use -2 in the history.back method.

HTML

```
<a id="goBack">Back</a>
```

JS

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.getElementById('goBack').addEventListener('click', () => {
        history.back(-2);
    });
});
</script>
```